# Eclipse generate "allocated object never used" errors in jmockit test

Tags: eclipse, jmockit, suppress-warnings

Using JMockIt 1.12 and Eclipse Luna and I get "The allocated object is never used" errors. 
I tried:

```
@Test
public void testNullCase() {

    new NonStrictExpectations() {{ 
         TestClass.getPlug();   
         result = null;
        }
...
    };
```

To use SuppressWarnings I had to use something ugly like this:

```
@Test
public void testNullCase() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    NonStrictExpectations dummy = new NonStrictExpectations() {{ 
         TestClass.getPlug();   
         result = null;
        }
...
    };
```

How to do this in a nicer way or am I missing something using JMockIt?

Comment: JDK 1.7.0-67 used if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning can be turned off via:

- opening the dialog `Window/Preferences`
- going to section `Java/Compiler/Errors&Warnings/Potential Programming problems`
- disabling `Unused object allocation`.

If you want to make that change persistent outside a particular Eclipse workspace, you can use the [workspace mechanic](https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/workspacemechanic/wiki/PreferenceRecorder). Or you could move the `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` to the test class to disable it for all tests in the class.

Comment: I disabled the error in Eclipse as you suggested, but I was hoping there was a better way in Jmockit or something and leaving Eclipse unchanged... This is the only drawback I've seen with JMockIt so far, but maybe same problem with like Mockito..?

Comment: This is more of a drawback of Eclipse. In IntelliJ IDEA, in comparison, I can configure any code inspection (including these and many, many others) *per scope*. So, for test code I configure a "test" scope where several warnings that are not useful get disabled, while leaving them enabled for production code. Hopefully, Eclipse will catch up some day.

Comment: Yes, maybe an Eclipse problem since you don't get any problem when compiling it outside Eclipse. I found that you can ignore compiler warnings in Eclipse per source folder now, in Properties for e.g. src/test folder. However Eclipse insist this an error so you still need to change it to a warning.